# Fail Over / Retry logic to support failover scenario with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

All,

Is there a pattern/approach to support a failover scenario in which the mongo primary goes down and a new replica is elected primary?  This results in a short outage until the driver reconnects to the primary.

I am looking for a place where I might be able to place logic that catches the connection exception, and then retry after a period of time.

Thanks,

Joe